# Get all Object attribute name of any nasted Object Array Dynamicly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

let say i have any nasted array Object and i want to get all the constructure of that Obj dinamicly

```
// any array
 // i use this array
    var person =    [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46},
                    {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", k:46},
                    {firstName:"John", o:"Doe", age:46},
                    {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", ppp:[]}];

//how about if it have one nested
    var person2 =    [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46},
                    {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", k:46},
                    {firstName:"John", o:"Doe", age:46},
                    {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", ppp:[{fa:"aa",ta:"asfa"},
                    {fa:"as"}]}];
    //i want to achive like this
    //["firstName", "lastName", "age", "k", "o", ppp: [fa,ta]]

//how about if it have many nested
    var person3 =    [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46},
                    {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", k:46 gg:[{ddd:
                     [{asar:""magrib}]}]},
                    {firstName:"John", o:"Doe", age:46 kk:["aaa"]},
                    {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", ppp:[{fa:"aa",ta:"asfa"},
                    {fa:"as"}]}];
```

and i running function to get the atribute but i just can do it in layer one, if this meet array of Object i want this function to generate the attribute name

```
function get_key (Obj,p){
  Obj.forEach(function(d,i){
  for ( property in d ) {
    var type =  typeof(d[property]) 
    if(p.indexOf(property)<0){

      if (type!=="object"){
        p.push(property)
        //console.log('ok')
      }else{

        //if meet object how can i make this do the same thing?
        // so it can dynamicly getattribute name 
        p[property]= p[property]='jj'
      }
     }
    }
  })
  return p
}

var p = get_key (person,[])
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = p;
 console.log(p)

//and if we console it it return
//["firstName", "lastName", "age", "k", "o", ppp: "jj"]
```

Comment: If you spend some time fixing the spelling, grammar and punctuation of your question you might get some answers. As it is, it's very hard to read. Using *Obj* as the name of a variable referencing an array is confusing.

Comment: sorry, but i just cant find the edit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it Can

```
function get_key (Obj,p,id){
var p2 
  Obj.forEach(function(d,i){
    if(typeof(d)!=='object'){
        return
    }
  for ( property in d ) {
    var type =  typeof(d[property]) 

    if(p.indexOf(property)<0){

      if (type!=="object"){
        p.push(property)
        //console.log('ok')
        //p[property]='jj'
      }else{
      console.log(property,[])
      var pe= property
        p2 = get_key (d[property],[],property)
        p[pe]=p2
      }
     }
    }
  })
  return p
}

var p = get_key (person,[])
```